# Cache multiple Dataframes in List Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, caching, persist

I've got a List[DataFrame] which consists of small size dataframes obtained from some joins from Snowflake tables.

The purpose is to cache each DF in the list to stay in memory for later.

Simplifying the case, what I've tried so far is to cache them and force an action:

```
val listDfs = [dfA, dfB, dfC]

val dfACached = listDfs.head.cache
// Force an action to enable fully cache on dfA
dfACached.count

val dfBCached = listDfs(2).cache
// Force an action to enable fully cache on dfB
dfBCached.count

val dfCCached = listDfs.last.cache
// Force an action to enable fully cache on dfC
dfCCached.count
```

Then I need to use these variables within a foreach loop to filter them out, so I include them on another list to be able to reference them:

```
val listDfsCached: List[DataFrame] = List(dfACached,dfBCached,dfCCached)
```

By now those three Dataframes should be cached in memory and fastly accessed.

Then Ive got an array of strings which are used to filter out the DFs:

```
val arrayFilters = ["a", "b", "c"]

listDfsCached.foreach(df => {
    val dfFiltered = df.filter(col("test") === str)
    // Finally I'll perform some other transformations and write a json file per string in the array
  }
}
```

What I can observe is DFs are not properly cached because during execution time, the program gets back to Snowflake to recalculate dfA, dfB, dfC to obtain dfFiltered every time.

Any ideas what Im doing wrong ?

Im using Spark version 3.2.1 in local debug (1 node - 4 cores)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the spark version and the cluster configurations?

Comment: @IslamElbanna Spark version 3.2.1 and its a local debug config (1 node - 4 cores)